# Questions about the Dirichlet series $K(s)=\sum\limits_{p^k} p^{\,-k\,s}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, mellin-transform

This question is related to Riemann's prime-power counting function $J(x)$, the fundamental prime-counting function $\pi(x)$, and the simple prime-power counting function $k(x)$ defined below where $p\in\mathbb{P}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

**(1)** $\quad J(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a_J(n)\,,\qquad  a_J(n)=\cases{\frac{1}{k},& $n=p^k$ \\ 0,& otherwise}$

**(2)** $\quad\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a_{\pi}(n)\,,\qquad a_{\pi}(n)=\cases{1,& $n\in\mathbb{P}$ \\ 0,& otherwise}$

**(3)** $\quad k(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a_k(n)\,,\qquad  a_k(n)=\cases{1,& $n=p^k$ \\ 0,& otherwise}$

---

The three prime counting functions defined above are related as follows where $rad(n)$ is the radical of $n$ (also referred to as the square-free kernel of $n$) which is the greatest square-free divisor of $n$.

---

**(4)** $\quad J(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)}\frac{1}{n}\,\pi\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$

**(5)** $\quad \pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\,J\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$

---

**(6)** $\quad K(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)}\pi\left(x^\frac{1}{n}\right)$

**(7)** $\quad \pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)}\mu(n)\,K\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$

---

**(8)** $\quad K(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)}\frac{\phi(n)}{n}\,J\left(x^\frac{1}{n}\right)$

**(9)** $\quad J(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)}\frac{\mu(rad(n))\,\phi(rad(n))}{n}\,K\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$

---

The three Dirichlet series defined below are related to the three prime-counting functions defined in (1) to (3) above.

---

**(10)** $\quad \log\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_J(n)}{n^s}\,,\quad\Re(s)>1$

**(11)** $\quad P(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_{\pi}(n)}{n^s}\,,\qquad\Re(s)>1\qquad\text{(prime zeta function)}$

**(12)** $\quad K(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_k(n)}{n^s}\,,\qquad\Re(s)>1$

---

I believe the $\log\zeta(s)$ function defined in (10) above can be analytically continued to the entire complex plane with branch points at $s=1$ and the zeros of $\zeta(s)$, and the prime zeta function $P(s)$ defined in (11) above can be analytically continued to the strip $0<Re(s)\le 1$ but not beyond the line $\Re(s)=0$. I've read very little is known about the zeros of the prime zeta function $P(s)$.

---

> **Question (1)**: Can the $K(s)$ function defined in (12) above be analytically continued beyond the line $\Re(s)=1$ and if so, what are the limits of this continuation?

---

> **Question (2)**: Is much known about the zeros of the $K(s)$ function defined in (12) above?

---

The prime zeta function $P(s)$ can be analytically continued as illustrated in formula (13) below. Based on formulas (5) and (8) above and formula (13) below, my guess is the function $K(s)$ can be analytically continued as illustrated in formula (14) below.

---

**(13)** $\quad P(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\,\log\zeta(n s)\,,\qquad\Re(s)>0$

**(14)** $\quad K(s)\stackrel{?}{=}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\phi(n)}{n}\,\log\zeta(n s)\,,\qquad\Re(s)>0?$

---

The following figure illustrates the imaginary part of formula (14) for $K(s)$ above in the interval $0<\Re(s)<1.2$ where the series in formula (14) is evaluated over the first 200 terms. Note $\Im(K(s))$ seems to take a negative step of magnitude $\frac{\phi(k)}{k}\pi$ at $s=\frac{1}{k}$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

[image: Plot[{Im@primeZetaK[s, 200]}, {s, 0, 1.2}, GridLines -> Automatic]]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (14) for $\Im(K(s))$

---

> **Question (3)**: Is it true the $K(s)$ function defined in formula (12) above can be analytically continued in the strip $0<Re(s)\le 1$ as illustrated in formula (14) above?

Comment: $\log \zeta(s)$ doesn't have poles but $\log(s)$ branch points at $s=1$ and the zeros of $\zeta(s)$... If you mean $K(s) = \sum_{p^k \le x} p^{-sk}$ then why do you care of its zeros ?

Comment: $\zeta'/\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic and the locations of its zeros are related to the location of its poles, thus we care of its zeros : the RH is true iff the zeros of $\zeta'$ are on $\Re(s) \ge 1/2$

Comment: @reuns I asked about the zeros of $K(s)$ because of the statement I saw about the $zeros$ of the prime zeta function $P(s)$. I was wondering if the function $K(s)$ is understood any better than the function $P(s)$.

Comment: @reuns I fixed the upper evaluation limits on formulas (10) to (12) which I initially neglected to update after copying them from formulas (1) to (3) as a starting point. I meant $K(s)=\sum\limits_{p^k} p^{\,-k\,s}$.

Comment: It is obvious that $K(s),P(s)$ are even messier than $\log \zeta(s)$ which is already a mess and whose "zeros" are not well-defined because of the many branches

Comment: @reuns Ok. What about the analytic continuation of $K(s)$?

Comment: @reuns $P(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\,\log\zeta(n s)$ is the analytic continuation of $P(s)$. Would $K(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\,\frac{\phi(n)}{n}\log\zeta(n s)$ be the analytic extension of $K(s)$?

Comment: Does it converge, is it analytic, does it match